# Why is $K_C^3$ very ample for smooth curves?

Tags: algebraic-curves

[image]

Here is a screenshot from [J. Alper](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Ejarod/moduli.pdf). I notice a fact about algebriac curves, that for a smooth curve $C$ of genus $g\geq2$, the line bundle $\Omega_C^{\otimes 3}$ is very ample.

Where can I find a reference for this statement?

Comment: Hartshorne proves that a line bundle is very ample if its degree is at least $2g+1$.